# Run terminal command from nodejs app through pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, socket.io, pm2

I have an `express server` running under `pm2` with just one route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html);
}
```

and a socket.io event handler that listens for "open youtube" (from the previously sent `index.html`)

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('open youtube', function() {
    exec('start chrome youtube.com'); //yes ik, this is a windows-only solution
    console.log('Opening youtube...');
  });
});
```

While everything does work, when emit is handled on the express server, the only part that works is the `console.log()` and not the `exec()` ( `const exec = require('child_process').exec;` )

What's the reason `pm2` doesn't allow me to run a `cmd` command and/or how can I run `cmd` command from a `nodejs` app running under `pm2` ?

EDIT:

When I run the server with npm start and not as a pm2 process, it opens a new tab ( as expected ) with youtube.com

EDIT 2:

For some reason, after I run pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js and pm2 save, it did work. The only change I made to ecosystem.config.js was to change exec_mode to exec_mode: 'cluster' instead of fork which is the default value.
I don't know if this was the reason or not.

Answer (score 1):

exec(String) is an asynchronous function,
You may have an error which your'e not aware of, pass a callback like this:

```
exec('start chrome youtube.com', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle success
  }
});
```

And you can also use the synchronous version

```
try {
  let res = execSync('start chrome youtube.com');
} catch(err){
  // handle error
  return;
}
// handle success
```

Comment: with the first approach `if(error) else`, the `else` statement is ran and I successfully run `console.log('youtube opened');` but chrome does not open

Comment: Please print all (stdout, stderr) to verify you don't have any error

Comment: b.t.w, "start chrome url" is not a default alias .   how did you setup this alias?

Comment: When I run the server with `npm start` and not as a `pm2` process, it opens a new tab ( as expected ) with youtube.com

Comment: For some reason, after I run `pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js` and `pm2 save`, it did work. The only change I made to `ecosystem.config.js` was to change `exec_mode` to `exec_mode: 'cluster'` instead of `fork` which is the default value

Comment: You changed how pm2 scales your app . With cluster mode (load balancing between workers) or just forks (individual workers)

Comment: I guess all it needed was a reload... Thank you for your time though